# Prove that decomposition of second order tensors into symmetric and skew components is unique.

Tags: tensors

Title says it all.

$A=A_{sym}+A_{skew}$

$A_{sym}= \dfrac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$

$A_{skew}= \dfrac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$

Anybody can help?

Comment: Have you tried just computing $A \pm A^T$ for $A = B + C$ where $B$ is symmetric and $C$ skew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $T=S_1+A_1=S_2+A_2$ are two symmetric skew-symmetric decompositions of rank two tensor. Then
$$0=T-T=(S_1+A_1)-(S_2+A_2)=(S_1-S_2)+(A_1-A_2)\\
0=0^T=(S_1-S_2)^T+(A_1-A_2)^T=(S_1-S_2)+(A_2-A_1)$$
Add up two equations produces
$$2(S_1-S_2)=0\Longrightarrow S_1=S_2$$
Minus equation 2 from 1 produces
$$2(A_1-A_2)=0\Longrightarrow A_1=A_2$$